# msysgit: git-upload-pack: command not found

Tags: git, clone, msysgit, pull

When cloning/pulling from an Git repository hosted on a Windows machine, I always keep getting

```
bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The system is running msysgit 1.7.11, access is done via SSH.
I already checked the %PATH% on the server and everything seems correct.

What to do?

Comment: It seems, msysgit is not aware of `git-upload-pack`, but it knows `git upload-pack`. (Note the space!)

What I did to fix the problem, was to create a new file in the ...Git\bin directory called `git-upload-pack` with the following content:

    #!/bin/bash
    git upload-pack $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9

This helps over the error message when pulling. But when pushing I get `git-receive-pack: command not found`.I now could also add a file for this one, but I already see myself creating a file for every Git command which is a really ugly and cumbersome solution...

Comment: The really weird thing is, the installation worked for months with an old Git version and after an update to 1.7.11 for several weeks. Then it broke from one day to the other. No updates of Git or Cygwin, after the 1.7.11 update were done.

Comment: To get to the same place you are, I followed this set of instructions: http://blog.chronosinteractive.com/posts/using-windows-server-host-git-repository